# Powershell Copy-item not working for unc paths

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am trying to sync two directories over the network between servers using UNC paths. The files are 20+ GB. I wrote a Powershell script to compare two directories and then copy any files missing from one to the other. However this doesn't appear to work.
Once the script is run it finds the files properly but when it tries to copy them it appears that the files are instantly copied (which is impossible). Even though the files take up 20+ GB of space on the hard drive they don't contain any data.

```
$SERVER1 = "SERVER1"
$SERVER2 = "SERVER2"
$VDISKPATH = "e$\vdisks"

#Automatically get vDisks and pvp files in VDISKPATH folder
$FILES1 = Get-ChildItem -Path \\$SERVER1\$VDISKPATH\* -Include *.vhd,*.pvp
$FILES2 = Get-ChildItem -Path \\$SERVER2\$VDISKPATH\* -Include *.vhd,*.pvp

if ( $FILES1 -and $FILES2 ) {
    $DIFF = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $FILES1 -DifferenceObject $FILES2 -Property name, length
}

# Copy all of the missing files from 
if ($DIFF) {
    $DIFF | Where-Object { $PSItem.SideIndicator -eq "<="} | ForEach-Object {
    Copy-Item "\\$SERVER1\$VDISKPATH\$($_.name)" -Destination \\$SERVER2\$VDISKPATH
    }
    $DIFF | Where-Object { $PSItem.SideIndicator -eq "=>"} | ForEach-Object { Write-Host "Copying $($_.name) to $SERVER1" |
    Copy-Item "\\$SERVER2\$VDISKPATH\$($_.name)" -Destination \\$SERVER1\$VDISKPATH
    }
Write-Host "All file copies have finished!"
}
else {
    Write-Host "All files are equal"
    Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $FILES1.name -DifferenceObject $FILES2.name -IncludeEqual
}
```

Typically the file copy (if done manually) takes about 15 minutes. I let the script run for 90 minutes and it never finished. Can someone help me figure out why the files are not coping properly?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `robocopy` for a task like that:

```
robocopy \\SERVER1\E$\vdisks \\SERVER2\E$\vdisks *.vhd *.pvp /z
```

Answer (score 0):

The pipeline output of your where-object will still be difference objects. So instead of:

```
$_.name
```

in your foreach, you want:

```
$_.InputObject.Name
```

Comment: I made that change but now it only copies an empty vdisks folder rather than copying the vhd and pvp files.

Comment: @rothgar I just noticed the -Property argument on your compare-object, so your code should work. Add a -WhatIf argument to your copy-item command and look to see if all the arguments are expanding as you expect.

Comment: I get `What if: Performing operation "Copy directory" on Target "Item: \\SERVER1\e$\vdisks\ Destination: \\SERVER2\e$\vdisks\vdisks"` Trying to track down if I left off a \ somewhere. When I take out the InputObject -whatif shows the correct .pvp and .vhd files. So the input object somehow changes what is actually being passed to the copy command.

Comment: your code works with local path ?what about net drives ? did you try to use bit transfert instead of copy-item ?